# CodeIgniter Datatables Server Side Date Range using Datepicker

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am in desperate need of help. For a few weeks, I have tried all the codes possible from the internet to get the Datatables serverside date range using the date picker in Codeigniter but no luck. If the dates are the same then I can get the range but if the range is between the day/month/year day I get a range of all the months or years that the day as. Please advise. Below is my codes for Codeigniter View, Controller and Model:-

**View Section**

```
    var table = $('.xtable').DataTable( {
     scrollY:        "400px",
    scrollX:        true,
     scrollCollapse: true,
    autoWidth:      true,
    paging:         false,
   fixedHeader: true,
   processing : true,
   serverSide : true,
   responsive: true,
    stateSave : true,
    deferRender: true,
    ajax: {
   "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>getallbillinglist",
   "type": "POST",
   "data": function ( data ) {
      console.log(data);
     data.startdate = $('#startdate').val();//$.trim(fdate1[0]);
      data.enddate = $('#enddate').val();//$.trim(fdate1[1]);
     console.log(data.startdate);
     console.log(data.enddate);
      return data;
    }
     }, ... code continues if not too long
  
   $('#startdate').datepicker({
      autoclose: true
    })

 $('#enddate').datepicker({
  autoclose: true
 })
 $('#startdate, #enddate').change(function () {
    console.log(this.value);
    table.draw();
    //table.columns(12).search(this.value ? '^'+this.value+'$' : '', true, false).draw(); 
    document.getElementById("sdate").value = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
    document.getElementById("edate").value = document.getElementById("enddate").value;
 });
```

**Controller Section**

```
       public function getallbillinglist()
        {
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
         {
            redirect('/');
        }
         $startdate = $this->input->post('startdate');
       $enddate = $this->input->post('enddate');
       $data['data']=$this->Job->get_allbillinglist($startdate,$enddate);
        echo json_encode($data);    
        }
```

**Model Section**

```
          function get_allbillinglist($startdate,$enddate)
{
    $data = array();
    $multipleWhere = ['invoices.Approved' => 1,'invoices.xero' => 0];
    $this->db->select('Client_Name, Invoice_No, Invoice_Date, Due_Date, Item_Descript, Quantity, UCost, Amt, TAmt, Tax, Total, AccCode, AccName, Ship_Name');
    $this->db->from("invoices");
    // $this->db->where('Approved',1);
    $this->db->where($multipleWhere);
    if($startdate!='' && $enddate!=''){
        //$this->db->where('invoices.Invoice_Date BETWEEN "'.$startdate.'" AND "'.$enddate.'"');
        $this->db->where('invoices.Invoice_Date >=', $startdate);
        $this->db->where('invoices.Invoice_Date <=', $enddate);
    }
    $this->db->get();  
    $query1 = $this->db->last_query();
    $multipleWhere1 = ['cninvoices.Approved' => 1, 'cninvoices.xero' => 0];
    $this->db->select('Client_Name, Credit_No, Credit_Date, "", Item_Descript, Quantity, UCost, TISubTotal, TIGST, Tax, TITotal, AccCode, AccName, Ship_Name');
    $this->db->from("cninvoices");
    // $this->db->where('Approved',1);
    $this->db->where($multipleWhere1);
    if($startdate!='' && $enddate!=''){
        // $this->db->where('cninvoices.Credit_Date BETWEEN "'.$startdate.'" AND "'.$enddate.'"');
        $this->db->where('cninvoices.Credit_Date >=', $startdate);
        $this->db->where('cninvoices.Credit_Date <=', $enddate);
    }
    $this->db->get(); 
    $query2 =  $this->db->last_query();
    $Q = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2." ORDER BY Invoice_No ASC");
    
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. I had to change the column type in my MYSQL table in PHPMyAdmin from varchar to date in order to get the date range.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with datepicker to me

Please change datepicker initializations like below

```
$('#startdate').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
});
$('#enddate').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
})
```

You can get values using jQuery like below

```
$('input[name=startdate]').val()
$('input[name=enddate]').val()
```

You can get POST values on the server side like below

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('startdate')));

$enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('enddate')));
```

If your DB is MSSQL, you can use those variables in your model query like below

```
$this->db->where('FORMAT(invoices.Invoice_Date, "yyyy-MM-dd") BETWEEN "'.$startdate.'" AND "'.$enddate.'"');
```

Please try and feedback

UPDATE

*This might help you*

FRONT END

HTML Markup

```
<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="<?php echo START_DATE; ?>" autocomplete="off" />

<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="<?php echo START_DATE; ?>" autocomplete="off" />
```

Datetimepicker Initialization

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format : 'dd.mm.yyyy',
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.YYYY',
  todayHighlight: true,
  language: 'tr',
  startView:2,
  minView:2
});

$('#end_date').datetimepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format : 'dd.mm.yyyy',
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.YYYY',
  todayHighlight: true,
  language: 'tr',
  startView:2,
  minView:2
});
```

Reformatting Function

```
function reformatDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b.reverse().join('-');
}
```

Ajax Post Data

```
var data = {
  start_date: reformatDateString($('#start_date').val()),
  end_date: reformatDateString($('#end_date').val()),
  csrf_test_name: csrfTokenHash
};
```

BACKEND

Controller

```
public function featured_meetings_list_json() {
  $data = array(
    'company_uid' => $this->session->userdata('COMPANY_UID'),
    'start_date' => $this->input->post('start_date'),
    'end_date' => $this->input->post('end_date'),
  );
  $result['data'] = $this->reports_model->get_featured_meetings($data);
  
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Model

```
public function get_featured_meetings($data) {
  $dataArr = array(
    $data['company_uid']
  );

  $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(m.document_no, '-', md.no) price_offer_no, m.document_no, m.document_date, e.name enterprise_name, CONCAT(u.name, ' ', u.lastname) sales_representative_name, p.name product_name, "
            ."md.quantity, CASE WHEN p.product_class = 0 and p.color = 0 THEN p.price WHEN p.product_class = 0 AND p.color = 1 THEN p.price + 0.50 WHEN p.product_class = 1 AND p.color = 0 THEN p.price + 0.20 WHEN p.product_class = 1 AND p.color = 1 THEN p.price + 0.70 WHEN p.product_class = 2 THEN p.price + 1.20 END list_price, p.currency_name list_price_currency_name, md.price, v.name vat_name, CAST(ROUND(((md.quantity)*(md.price)*(100 + v.rate)/100), 2) AS NUMERIC(36,2)) total_price, c.name currency_name, pt.name payment_type_name "
            ."FROM meetings m "
            ."LEFT JOIN meeting_details md ON(m.company_uid = md.company_uid AND m.uid = md.meeting_uid) "
            ."LEFT JOIN enterprises e ON (m.company_uid = e.company_uid AND m.enterprise_uid = e.uid) "
            ."LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.uid, p.company_uid, p.name, p.color, p.product_class, pc.price, pc.currency_uid, c.name currency_name, c.sign FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON (p.product_category_uid = pc.uid) LEFT JOIN currencies c ON (pc.currency_uid = c.uid)) AS p ON (md.company_uid = p.company_uid AND md.product_uid = p.uid) "
            ."LEFT JOIN users u ON (m.company_uid = u.company_uid AND m.sales_representative_uid = u.uid) "
            ."LEFT JOIN currencies c ON (md.currency_uid = c.uid) "
            ."LEFT JOIN vats v ON (md.vat_uid = v.uid) "
            ."LEFT JOIN payment_types pt ON (md.company_uid = pt.company_uid AND md.payment_type_uid = pt.uid) "
            ."WHERE m.company_uid = ?";

  if($data['start_date'] != '' && $data['end_date'] != '') {
    array_push($dataArr, $data['start_date']);
    array_push($dataArr, $data['end_date']);
    $sql .= " AND FORMAT(m.document_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') between ? AND ?";
  }

  $sql .= " ORDER BY total_price DESC";
  //Here you can check your query and variables and run the query in console to catch potential issues, e.x. error_log(print_r($dataArr, true));error_log($sql);
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, $dataArr);
  return (array)$query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: I am using PHPMyAdmin and MySql what should my DB be?

Comment: Then please change FORMAT(invoices.Invoice_Date, "yyyy-MM-dd") into DATE(invoices.Invoice_Date) and try

Comment: But the better way to spot any problems is using error_log on backend.

error_log($startdate);error_log($enddate);

Get the values from logs and try to run your query with those variables, mysql will give you clue.

Comment: Tried your method but had no luck. where should I put error_log?

Comment: In your model method, if that does not work, I will share a complete example in my answer

Comment: Ya, I tried error_log in the model but it does not work.
I tried using moment and nothing works.
Here are the plugin 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: The updates do not work.

Comment: You should get the running sql command and related variables on the server side and then run the sql command on a new query window with provided variables. That way, you can solve that error. Try this route.

Comment: No Luck Bro. I am not able to even convert string date to date so the range can happen.

Comment: I have been focusing on the model section of the Codeigniter and it seems the problem is there. The string to string date range will not work and looks like the string need to be converted to date. But still having difficulties.

Comment: I have posted another new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361303/codeigniter-model-date-range