# CodeIgniter Model Date Range

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I have been struggling for a few weeks. Recently I posted a question here [CodeIgniter Datatables Server Side Date Range using Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70331094/codeigniter-datatables-server-side-date-range-using-datepicker) but no luck.

Then I decide to isolate the problem by testing the Codeigniter Model and seems like there is a problem there.

Below is the code and image.

**Codeigniter Model**

```
function get_allbillinglistByDate($startdate,$enddate){
    $data = array();
    $sdate = "09/01/2020";
    $edate = "11/01/2020";
    $this->db->from('invoices');
    $multipleWhere = ['invoices.Approved' => 1,'invoices.xero' => 0];
    $this->db->where($multipleWhere);
    //$this->db->where('Invoice_Date BETWEEN "'. date('m-d-Y', strtotime($sdate)). '" and "'. date('m-d-Y', strtotime($edate)).'"');
    $this->db->where('Invoice_Date >=', date('m-d-Y', strtotime($sdate)));
    $this->db->where('Invoice_Date <=', date('m-d-Y', strtotime($edate)));
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

Here is the screenshot
[Date Column where only 2020 record should show but it shows 2021 too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTo7P.png)

Not sure where things are going wrong the date Column where only 2020 record should show but it shows 2021 too

Please advise.

Comment: it DB date will stored as `Y-m-d` format, you have to use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate))`

Answer (score 0):

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98'). To convert strings in other orders to year-month-day order, the STR_TO_DATE() function may be useful.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

So, change your code as below

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate)
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Based on your suggestion I made the changes but now I cannot load the entire database. My date column in the database is in the following format d/m/Y eg. 09/01/2020 Please advice thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Raj is correct. You can tweak it according to your expected format like below

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($sdate));
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($edate));
```

An alternative syntax of your method but you may need to tweak it a little. You should format date params and then send them to this method, you can format them as we described

```
function get_allbillinglistByDate($startdate,$enddate){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM invoices where Approved = 1 AND xero = 0 AND DATE(Invoice_Date) BETWEEN ? AND ?"; 

  $data = array();
  array_push($data, $startdate);
  array_push($data, $enddate);

  $query = $this->db->query($sql, $dataArr);
  return (array)$query->result_array();
}
```

For more info check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hi Ahmet, Thank you for assisting but your codes do not work. The date column in Mysql is saved in Varchar not sure if that could be a problem.

Comment: Both start date and end date is from the same column

Answer (score 0):

ok guys the problem is resolved. I had to change the column type in my MYSQL table in PHPMyAdmin from varchar to date in order to get the date range.